# Trying to add rows to a tablelayout in a loop

Tags: android

I'm trying to add rows with columns to a table layout using 2 for loops. When I did it manually, without loops, it worked but now it doesn't display anything nor does it give me any errors.

```
    TableLayout dataTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.standingsData);
    Integer[] dataOrder = {1, 0, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int i=0; i < rssFeedStandings.size() ; i++)
    {
        TableRow dataTableRow = new TableRow(this);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams dataTableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dataTableRow.setLayoutParams(dataTableRowParams);
        dataTableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_row);
        for(int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
            TextView textview = new TextView(this);
            textview.setText(rssFeedStandings.get(i)[dataOrder[j]]);
            textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(j));
            textview.setTypeface(tf2);

            dataTableRow.addView(textview);

            }
        dataTable.addView(dataTableRow, dataTableRowParams);
        Log.d(TAG, "Got here!!!");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, still new to android development.

Comment: stupid question: does your rssFeedStandings contain data? :)

Comment: and btw, don't use TableLayout, use ListView + ArrayAdapter instead.

Comment: Oh I've just been blindly using TableLayouts guess I should look into other options as well thanks